# Question that answers my question doesn't show up in search

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked a question and it was flagged as a duplicate, and linked to another question. The other question did have the answer I was looking for, but the question was really very different. My question was about Contacts and Accounts, and the answer was about Opportunities and Accounts. I even searched for more generic master-detail/lookup and object relationship keywords, but it never showed up.

So this seems like an issue with discoverability. The person who flagged my question as a duplicate was the answerer to the other question, so I'm guessing that's how he knew. But maybe he's just a better searcher than me. Is there a way for a user to add keywords or comments to a question to help the search algorithm?

My question was about how to get a list of accounts from a list of contacts in apex and the question it was duplicating is [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117699/i-am-trying-to-copy-the-fax-number-from-account-to-opportunity).

Comment: FYI I deleted my question because it was a bad question and got downvoted. Had it been properly asked would it have been better to leave it so someone else might find it? But I don't think duplicates show up in the search either.

Comment: Duplicates do show up in the search and it is strongly encourage to leave them. If they're racking up downvotes, however, you can hardly be blamed.